# Books/courses for math-interested 17 year old?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, analysis, statistics, book-recommendation

I'm a 17 year old junior looking to further develop my mathematical skills in order to better prepare myself for university level pure mathematics. I'm looking for books/courses in Analysis, Linear Algebra, Discrete Maths, Combinatorics, Statistics or anything that could be helpful. I've already applied to different universities for summer courses but would also like to get more information by people who have studied maths themselves.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At 17 years old most students are introduced to subjects involving algebra pre-calculus, entry calculus and some basic linear algebra. Combinatorics and Discrete Maths, at least where I study, are taught in the 2nd-3rd year of university and rightfully so, as they use tools from previous courses. As far as Statistics are concerned, one can study elementary stuff  and an entry-level course fairly easy.

Comment: It sounds like you are ahead of the game in mathematics. Perhaps your time would be better spent with literature, art and music. Physical fitness should also be prioritized at your age. The very best mathematicians are pretty well rounded.

Comment: I liked the book [numbers](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387974972). It develops much more than skills, it makes one curious about mathematics. I think, this is perhaps more important.

Comment: @JohnDouma I play soccer at a youth level and train 6 times a week. Have read some books of Dostoevsky(definitely not enough but still). I might be a little ahead of the game but I'm sure there are others much better than me. Would just like to know if there's anything that could help me go to a top university in the future and use my time wisely

Comment: I was not being facetious. I have no doubt that you will get into a good university. You are at a point in your life with few limitations. I truly believe a young person like you should develop all aspects of yourself and hold off on specialization. It sounds like you understand that so keep going; upward and onward as they say.

Comment: Anything by Ross Honsberger, the Yaglom brothers or Titu Andreescu (ideally joint with Gabriel Dospinescu) will likely be useful (but don't force yourself into it -- browse until you find something you're curious about; most of these books can be read diagonally).

Comment: One way to achieve your goal would be to look up some syllabuses from the courses you expect to take at a university you might get in to. They will often have textbook information. You're unlikely to find any gems but there's no better way to simulate the university experience.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers!
JohnDouma I didn't mean it in a bad way either. Thanks!
DisplayName I've tried, but they are too vague and/or left as extra work after mostly being taught in lectures 
@darijgrinberg I've hear about those. Will surely give it a go

Comment: @BjornRambi You might want to consider reaching out to a local university and see if any math professors would be willing to meet with you semi-regularly to hang out and chat about math. I (graduate student, not professor) met with a high schooler weekly all of last semester, and we discussed a variety of “higher” mathematics in varying degrees of formality.

Comment: @SantanaAfton I’ve tried that too as well as contacting the my country’s mathematical association, but they don’t seem to bother or have any slight interest into helping ‍♂️

Comment: @BjornRambi Hm, that’s unfortunate. Perhaps you could reach out to some graduate students and ask for their advice — hopefully they would be more willing to meet with you.

Answer (score 2):

You might enjoy *[Combinatorics Through Guided Discovery](https://bogart.openmathbooks.org/)*.

Answer (score 0):

For introductory book on analysis, I would recommend Stephen Abbott's *Understanding Analysis*. It's written both very cleanly and concisely, giving it the advantage of being extremely readable, all without missing the formalities of analysis that are the focus at this level, especially if you are self studying. After this book, you may proceed with baby Rudin or Bartle's *Elements of Real Analysis*

For linear algebra, Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done right* and Gilbert Strang's *Linear Algebra and Its Applications* are the books to go with.

For abstract algebra, Fraleigh's *A First Course in Abstract Algebra, 7th Edition* is a good book for self study. It is easy and good for the beginners, and it has a complete solution manual written by the author.

Comment: Please. Axler is well-written but teaches bad algebra. Strang is oftentimes incomprehensible without a lecturer.